# testing requests for responses in wiremock

Tags: json, request, testng, wiremock

I am testing requests using wiremock

the first request is a status 200 request

```
 {
    "request": {
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/egateway/simphonyposapiweb.asmx",
      "headers": {
        "SOAPAction": {
          "equalTo": "\"http://micros-hosting.com/EGateway/CalculateTransactionTotalsEx\""
        }
      }
    },
        "response": {
          "status": 200,
          "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "text/xml"
          },
          "bodyFileName": "CalculateTransactionTotalsExResponse.xml"
        }
      }
```

the other test should be a 200 but slow response

Can I add "`fixedDelayMilliseconds": 2000`

I also need to test an error response too.  Would the status be changed to 500?

Sorry I am new to this and your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to get different responses to the exact same request?